# How to scrape "Shadow Content" with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to web scrape a players Madden ratings with BeautifulSoup. I want to get the stats from [this player](https://www.ea.com/games/madden-nfl/player-ratings/player-name/Devin%20McCourty/9925). But, when I inspected the HTML I saw the ratings were in the "Shadow Content" part, and I can't seem to scrape that.

[image: Image that shows the ratings are in "Shadow Content"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with `JavaScript` website which render the inner HTML once the page fully loaded. `requests` will not be able to Render `JS` for you.

In that case you've to lookup for the `API` which feed the inner `HTML`, in your case is below:

```
import requests
from pprint import pp


def main(url):
    params = {
        'filter': 'iteration:* AND primaryKey:9925',
        'sort': 'iteration:Asc'
    }
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    pp(r.json()['docs'][0])


main('https://ratings-api.ea.com/v2/entities/m22-ratings')
```

Output:

```
{'college': 'Rutgers',
 'awareness_rating': 94,
 'throwPower_rating': 30,
 'kickReturn_rating': 74,
 'leadBlock_rating': 22,
 'strength_rating': 62,
 'bCVision_rating': 65,
 'catchInTraffic_rating': 45,
 'playAction_rating': 6,
 'pursuit_rating': 85,
 'plyrAssetname': 'McCourtyDevin_9925',
 'mediumRouteRunning_rating': 13,
 'catching_rating': 80,
 'acceleration_rating': 91,
 'spinMove_rating': 75,
 'height': 70,
 'finesseMoves_rating': 45,
 'spectacularCatch_rating': 61,
 'runBlock_rating': 35,
 'tackle_rating': 74,
 'injury_rating': 95,
 'zoneCoverage_rating': 92,
 'weight': 195,
 'plyrBirthdate': '8/13/87',
 'runningStyle_rating': 'Short Stride Loose',
 'deepRouteRunning_rating': 10,
 'firstName': 'Devin',
 'yearsPro': 11,
 'totalSalary': 10000000,
 'trucking_rating': 28,
 'throwAccuracyShort_rating': 6,
 'position': 'FS',
 'jukeMove_rating': 77,
 'playRecognition_rating': 90,
 'shortRouteRunning_rating': 15,
 'status': 'published',
 'lastName': 'McCourty',
 'jerseyNum': 32,
 'breakSack_rating': 14,
 'speed_rating': 91,
 'runBlockPower_rating': 35,
 'jumping_rating': 92,
 'toughness_rating': 77,
 'throwOnTheRun_rating': 6,
 'manCoverage_rating': 85,
 'stiffArm_rating': 25,
 'powerMoves_rating': 35,
 'iteration': 'launch-ratings',
 'release_rating': 12,
 'hitPower_rating': 67,
 'throwAccuracyMid_rating': 6,
 'kickAccuracy_rating': 24,
 'passBlockPower_rating': 35,
 'impactBlocking_rating': 67,
 'stamina_rating': 97,
 'carrying_rating': 50,
 'breakTackle_rating': 62,
 'plyrPortrait': 2043,
 'kickPower_rating': 22,
 'plyrHandedness': 'Right',
 'throwUnderPressure_rating': 23,
 'team': 'Patriots',
 'signingBonus': 6550000,
 'passBlock_rating': 35,
 'changeOfDirection_rating': 87,
 'press_rating': 86,
 'throwAccuracyDeep_rating': 6,
 'archetype': 'S_Zone',
 'blockShedding_rating': 64,
 'runBlockFinesse_rating': 35,
 'teamId': 22,
 'agility_rating': 89,
 'fullNameForSearch': 'Devin McCourty',
 'overall_rating': 92,
 'passBlockFinesse_rating': 35,
 'age': 34,
 'primaryKey': 9925}
```

Pickup whatever you need :).